# GWT RPC Cookie authentication

Tags: java, authentication, gwt, cookies

I'm using gwt on my glassfish server, and I'm attempting to make some of my RPC calls authenticated via cookies. Is this possible? Are there any examples out there of how to code it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending only on the cookie for authentication will make your website/services vulnerable to Cross-Site Request Forging/XSRF/CSRF attacks - read more on that in [Security for GWT Applications](http://groups.google.com/group/google-web-toolkit/web/security-for-gwt-applications).

The best way would be to double check the value you get from the cookie and with the one that's been transported to the server by some other means - as part of the request (header, a custom field, etc).

Other than that, there are many tutorials covering the subject - just search for Java (servlet) authentication - it doesn't have to be GWT-specific. The [Google Web Toolkit Group](http://groups.google.com/group/google-web-toolkit) also has many [threads](http://groups.google.com/group/google-web-toolkit/browse_thread/thread/e8e14b16e57b266f/0f296a1553d18049) [about](http://groups.google.com/group/google-web-toolkit/browse_thread/thread/e3dc56f7e4199caf/30fb2a9083e137ff) [the](http://groups.google.com/group/google-web-toolkit/browse_thread/thread/6e8989af81306421/6609a58436180f91) [subject](http://groups.google.com/group/google-web-toolkit/browse_thread/thread/3ca02837f8108f99/cbb0efb4c8c1ed45).

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you use GWT's RPC servlet for handling requests made by the client.

One option that comes to my mind is to write and configure a ServletFilter which can examine the cookie, before the request reaches GWT's servlet.

Answer (score 0):

You might rethink using cookies as it is a potencial security hole.
Why not put your communication to HTTPS?

Comment: HTTPS doesn't prevent XSRF attacks, AFAIK, so you're "just" protected from man-in-the-middle attacks. And it has the additional quirk that makes most browsers **not** cache the content of the HTTPS request. Plus, with GWT and all the AJAX stuff, you either keep the website HTTP or HTTPS - mixing them up can lead to some scary warnings on some browsers - not something you want to show to your users :)

Comment: True ... but I was thinking putting the whole site under HTTPS not mixing it.

Comment: Right, and then the users would have to download the whole application (JS files) every time they use the site, probably complaining how slow it's loading, etc. Of course, if this is a bank site or something similar, security is priority number 1 and the whole site should be https. Nevertheless, my point about cookie-only authentication still holds.

Answer (score 0):

Can you not just use the standard 'session' scope, i.e.

```
request.getSession()
```

A pattern I use in GWT apps is to have a separate 'old fashioned' login form which sets up the session. The GWT app's host page is then displayed after they have successfully logged in.

If the necessary values aren't in the session, then the user isn't logged in. Your service should return an exception, maybe, which instructs the GWT app to redirect to the login page, or display an error.

Comment: Not sending a custom session id with every RPC payload potentially leaves RPC services open to XSRF/CSRF attacks